# I cannot get user's informations in facebook api php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook api for PHP. 
i can get only basic information like username,fullname,link,id.
i cannot get country,email,place..etc

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphLocation.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphLocation;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '518573344952566','a3afc2397a81e216e60714f83142e2f9' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/1353/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  /*
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email'); 
$fplace=$graphObject->getProperty('place'); 
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/

// Get the base class GraphObject from the response
// Get the base class GraphObject from the response
$object = $response->getGraphObject();

// Get the response typed as a GraphUser
$user = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
// or convert the base object previously accessed
// $user = $object->cast(GraphUser::className());

// Get the response typed as a GraphLocation
$loc = $response->getGraphObject(GraphLocation::className());
// or convert the base object previously accessed
// $loc = $object->cast(GraphLocation::className());

// User example
echo $object->getProperty('name');
echo $user->getName();


// Location example
echo $object->getProperty('country');
echo $loc->getCountry();
 echo $object->getProperty('email');
// SessionInfo example
$info = $session->getSessionInfo();
echo $info->getxpiresAt();
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

This is my code, When i print like country , email ,place, it shows nothing ! 
when i print `$response`
it shows following

```
Facebook\FacebookRequest Object ( [session:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => Facebook\FacebookSession Object ( [accessToken:Facebook\FacebookSession:private] => Facebook\Entities\AccessToken Object ( [accessToken:protected] => CAAHXo8QEEPYBAPwxcD0DT08AuysfOCGl7TWYCViyZB0PnXFQGB5LrfreJh3hxM1xtDQpD7zqJReTJESo96VS4Wi2qIQRKzpMaWZCBkTFIlHzyhbq96k8aXJGdS77jysotckuGEcgyCPJp7veRyJL4SZCN8a9m9sZAKtcvS3ZCLO6COorMTQKSYAyJAXkYuIb1biS7sLd0MMhH3c9aylAJ [machineId:protected] => [expiresAt:protected] => ) [signedRequest:Facebook\FacebookSession:private] => ) [method:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => GET [path:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => /me [params:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => Array ( [access_token] => CAAHXo8QEEPYBAPwxcD0DT08AuysfOCGl7TWYCViyZB0PnXFQGB5LrfreJh3hxM1xtDQpD7zqJReTJESo96VS4Wi2qIQRKzpMaWZCBkTFIlHzyhbq96k8aXJGdS77jysotckuGEcgyCPJp7veRyJL4SZCN8a9m9sZAKtcvS3ZCLO6COorMTQKSYAyJAXkYuIb1biS7sLd0MMhH3c9aylAJ [appsecret_proof] => fbd9e3248da5678fc68be8bfcee6368ed56fdf71507d16d7b19dc494c22280dc ) [version:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => v2.2 [etag:Facebook\FacebookRequest:private] => )
```

Comment: what happens when you `print_r($response);`

Comment: check my question i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not asking for any additional permissions, of course you don´t get email or other specifics without authorizing with the needed permissions.

Check out this page to find out how to ask for additional permissions in the authorization process:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl

For example, if you want to get the email of the user, you would have to add the "email" permission. For the user location, you need to ask for "user_location".

Comment: Thank you in which file i should add extra permission ?

Comment: file? in your code, obviously. did you click on the link i posted?

Answer (score 1):

In case if an example required (how to ask permissions):

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.com/callback');
    $params = array('email','public_profile', 'user_status', 'user_friends');
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change in API request like this then you definitely get facebook email id.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email' );
```

If you want to get more user's information you can go like this:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,gender'.......etc );
```